# TypeError: test() missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest, text-mining, nose

I want to predict a score for each sentence in a text. I have written this test method:

```
def test(sent):
    # Predict for a given sentence
    if sent != "":
        input, seq_lengths, target = make_variables([sent], [])
        output = classifier(input, seq_lengths)
        pred = output.data.max(1, keepdim=True)[1]
        score = pred.cpu().numpy()[0][0]
        print("The sentence is:",sent, "The score is:", score)
        return


    print("evaluating trained model ...")
    total_mse=0

    for sents, scores in test_loader:
        input, seq_lengths, target = make_variables(sents, scores)
        output = classifier(input, seq_lengths)
        pred = output.data.max(1, keepdim=True)[1]
        error=mean_squared_error(pred,target.data.view_as(pred.float()))
        total_mse +=error
    print(" **********  Total MSE is   **********",total_mse)
    return
```

In a part of main method, I have:

```
# Testing
test("")
# Testing for a given sample _a sentence_
test("For instance, wolves prey on moose, which are too big for coyotes.")
```

But I received this error:

> Error Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/mahsa/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_env/lib/python3.5/unittest/case.py",
>   line 59, in testPartExecutor
>       yield   File "/home/mahsa/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_env/lib/python3.5/unittest/case.py",
>   line 601, in run
>       testMethod()   File "/home/mahsa/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nose/case.py",
>   line 198, in runTest
>       self.test(*self.arg) Exception: test() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sent'
>   -------------------- >> begin captured logging << -------------------- gensim.models.doc2vec: DEBUG: Fast version of gensim.models.doc2vec is
>   being used summa.preprocessing.cleaner: INFO: 'pattern' package not
>   found; tag filters are not available for English gensim.utils: INFO:
>   loading KeyedVectors object from
>   /home/mahsa/PycharmProjects/PyTorch_env_project/Thesis/proj2/glove_saved
>   gensim.utils: INFO: loading syn0 from
>   /home/mahsa/PycharmProjects/PyTorch_env_project/Thesis/proj2/glove_saved.syn0.npy
>   with mmap=None gensim.utils: INFO: setting ignored attribute syn0norm
>   to None gensim.utils: INFO: loaded
>   /home/mahsa/PycharmProjects/PyTorch_env_project/Thesis/proj2/glove_saved
>   --------------------- >> end captured logging << ---------------------
>
> E
>   ====================================================================== ERROR: mahsa_rnn_sent_classification.test
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/mahsa/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nose/case.py",
>   line 198, in runTest
>       self.test(*self.arg) TypeError: test() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sent'
>   -------------------- >> begin captured logging << -------------------- gensim.models.doc2vec: DEBUG: Fast version of gensim.models.doc2vec is
>   being used summa.preprocessing.cleaner: INFO: 'pattern' package not
>   found; tag filters are not available for English gensim.utils: INFO:
>   loading KeyedVectors object from
>   /home/mahsa/PycharmProjects/PyTorch_env_project/Thesis/proj2/glove_saved
>   gensim.utils: INFO: loading syn0 from
>   /home/mahsa/PycharmProjects/PyTorch_env_project/Thesis/proj2/glove_saved.syn0.npy
>   with mmap=None gensim.utils: INFO: setting ignored attribute syn0norm
>   to None gensim.utils: INFO: loaded
>   /home/mahsa/PycharmProjects/PyTorch_env_project/Thesis/proj2/glove_saved
>   --------------------- >> end captured logging << ---------------------
>
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Ran 1 test in 0.004s
>
> FAILED (errors=1)

I think that test() has its argument 'sent'. How can I correct this error?

Comment: Please include the complete error message.

Comment: I edited my question by adding full error comment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Running tests with `nose` or [`unittest`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/unittest.html) is not trivial, if you're new at this, I think you would have an easier time getting started with something like [`pytest`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/)

Comment: I try running my code by pytest instead of nostest by trying this path: `Pycharm->Settings->Tools->Python Integrated Tools-> Default Test Runner=py.test.' But when I right click on my python file in Pycharm, there is still `Run/Debug Nosetest in myfile.py`. How can I change this to pytest?

Comment: No pb, if you cannot use it, then have a look at the unittest tutorials to see how to build the test classes